# Need to create, use and store dynamic object names in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, object, checkbox, dynamic

I am loading in a text file and looping through each line, and trying to print a checkbox, in a powershell form. However, the way below, all checkboxes have the same variable/object name, which makes it impossible to tell them apart.

I need a way to dynamically create $checkbox0 through $checkbox(# of lines in text file, which can change), and fill them in below, as well as store the names, so i can validate if they are clicked later

```
$pFile = Get-Content "C:\results.txt"
$rowCounter = 0
foreach($line in $pFile){
    $checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $checkbox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $checkbox.AutoSize = "true"
    $checkbox.TabIndex = $rowCounter
    $checkbox.Text = $line
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 25
    $yValue = (20 * $rowCounter)
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = $yValue
    $checkbox.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $checkbox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Form1.Controls.Add($checkbox)
    $rowCounter = $rowCounter + 1
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't simply use an array instead of individually named numbered variables?

Comment: Care to elaborate? I dont know how many rows of the text file there will be, so i dont know how many variables i will need.

Comment: What do you think you can do via `$checkbox0` that you cannot do via `$checkbox[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

`Control` has `Name` property which is a string. Assigning a unique name to the control, you can find it later in the `Controls` collection of the parent control.

Also if you correctly assign an event handler to an event of the control, you can receive the control in the sender parameter of the event handler.

In the following code, I've created a list of `CheckBox` controls and handles their `CheckedChanged` event for them:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$flp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$form.Controls.Add($flp)
#Let's say you read the following values from file
$array = ("Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor") 
$i = 0
$array | % {
    $checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $checkBox.Text = $_
    $checkBox.Name = "checkBox_$i"
    $flp.Controls.Add($checkBox)
    $checkBox.Add_CheckedChanged({
        $index = $flp.Controls.IndexOf($this)
        $name = $this.Name
        $text = $this.Text
        $value = $this.Checked
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Index: $index" +"`n" +
            "Name: $name" + "`n" +
            "Text: $text" + "`n" +
            "Value: $value" + "`n")
    })
    $i++
}
$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```